# Sorting in SSMS object explorer details view

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have the developer edition of SQL Server 2012 installed on Win7 Pro x64. From Management Studio I can pull up the object explorer details view and see a list of say, all tables in a given database. If I sort by schema, I'd like it to subsequently sort by table name. But it doesn't do that. It uses some other mystery attribute to order tables within a given schema.

Is it possible to sort by a second column, or change the second-level sorting so it looks at the table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Object Explorer Details only supports single-level sorting, just like `ORDER BY x` in SQL Server will order `y` in an arbitrary way.

Comment: Only one column sorting order is applied - Reference below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646011%28v=sql.110%29.aspx